# Hugo Theme Academic: Rename "interests" in about section

Tags: r, hugo, hugodown

I'm setting up a Hugo website, theme academic, in R via `hugodown`. In the "about" section is a column named "interests" which I want to rename into "work".

What I have done so far:

The `content/authors/admin/_index.md` file contains following code:

```
interests: # <- I want to rename this into 'work'
- Artificial Intelligence
- Computational Linguistics
- Information Retrieval
```

If only this file is renamed then the whole column "interests" won't show.

There is another file `layouts/partial/widgets/about.html` which contains the following code:

```
  {{ with $person.interests }}
  <div class="col-md-5">
    <h3>{{ i18n "interests" | markdownify }}</h3>
    <ul class="ul-interests">
      {{ range . }}
      <li>{{ . | markdownify | emojify }}</li>
      {{ end }}
    </ul>
  </div>
  {{ end }}
```

Additional to the above change, naming `with $person.interests` into `with $person.work` will show the column again, but it is still called "interests". When additionally changing the `i18n "interests"` in the `<h3>` tag into `i18n "work"` the heading "interests" is removed and only the content of the column is displayed without a heading.

It seems like the new column name "work" has to be registered somewhere else, before it is properly display.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After fiddling around I found the answer to my question. As I expected there is a file in which all `id`s and their `translation` are registred. It depends on the choosen language. If the chosen language is English `en` then it is enough to go to the folder: `themes/academic/i18n/` and open the file `en.yaml`. Here we find:

```
# About widget

- id: interests
  translation: Interests
```

This can be changed to:

```
- id: interests
  translation: Work
```

Now the website will properly display "Work" instead of "Interests" on the About widget page.

Comment: I wonder if you can help me to identify a place in my [git hub repo](https://github.com/yuliaUU/KC-design/tree/main/config/_default). I do not have themes/academic/i18n/ folder

Comment: I did it using custom.scss document, But I don't think it is an ideal way to do it

Comment: @yuliaUUTry: "themes\github.com\wowchemy\wowchemy-hugo-modules\wowchemy\v5\i18n"